# Merge Map in java restoring insertion order

Tags: java

I have 3 map of same type. map1 being the highest priority map, map2 a lesser priority, and map3 being the least priority.

```
 Map<Integer, String> map1 = {2="two", 4="four"};
 Map<Integer, String> map2 = {2="twotwo", 1="one",3="three"};
 Map<Integer, String> map3 = {1="oneone", 5="five"};
```

Finally i want merged map to be like

```
 Map<Integer, String> mergedmap = {2="two", 4="four",1="one",3="three",5="five"};
```

Basic algorithm to be followed

1. Add all entries of map1 to merged map.
2. Add entries of map2 to merged map, skip entry if its key is already present.
3. Add entries of map3 to merged map, skip entry if its key is already present.

I have tried

```
    Map<Integer, String> mergeMap = new HashMap<Integer,String>(map3);
    mergeMap.putAll(map2);
    mergeMap.putAll(map1);
```

Outcome of this is

```
   Map<Integer, String> mergedmap = {1="one", 2="two", 3="three", 4="four", 5="five"};
```

Data is correct but not in the sequence i need. How this can be done ? Below is the test class

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


public class MapTest {
public static void main(String[] args){

     Map<Integer, String> map1 = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
     map1.put(2, "two");
     map1.put(4, "four");

     Map<Integer, String> map2 =  new HashMap<Integer, String>();
     map2.put(2, "twotwo");
     map2.put(1, "one");
     map2.put(3, "three");

     Map<Integer, String> map3 = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
     map3.put(1, "oneone");
     map3.put(5, "five");

     Map<Integer, String> mergeMap = new HashMap<Integer,String>(map3);
     mergeMap.putAll(map2);
     mergeMap.putAll(map1);
     System.out.println(mergeMap);

}
}
```

Comment: How about using a LinkedHashmap rather than just HashMap?

Comment: Converting all HahMap to LinkedHashMap in test class is outputting result as {1=one, 5=five, 2=two, 3=three, 4=four}, which again is not the one i need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `putIfAbsent` method to ensure the right entries are in the map.

```
Map<Integer, String> mergedMap = new HashMap<>(map1);
map2.forEach((k, v) -> mergedMap.putIfAbsent(k, v);
map3.forEach((k, v) -> mergedMap.putIfAbsent(k, v);
```

Sorting is best done when you use the entries rather than when you are creating them:

```
mergedMap.entrySet().stream()
    .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue)
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Great but only if he is using JDK 1.8 :)

Comment: @SanjeevDhiman Java 8 came out more than 2 years - surely we can assume OPs are using it now?

Comment: Many of my projects are still on JDK 1.6 :) Yeah, I know they must be changed but looks like my clients have different priorities. Nonetheless, I agree with you.

Comment: All 20 million loc in our project is on 1.6

Comment: Yeah, I forget to mention, I am using Java 8. This answers is correct except that LinkedHashMap has to be used instead. Thanks @sprinter, you made my day !!

Answer (score 1):

I wonder why would you want to maintain a sequence in a map but if you indeed do then you should use linkedHashMap. See this -

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<Integer, String> map1 = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    map1.put(2, "two");
    map1.put(4, "four");

    Map<Integer, String> map2 = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    map2.put(2, "twotwo");
    map2.put(1, "one");
    map2.put(3, "three");

    Map<Integer, String> map3 = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    map3.put(1, "oneone");
    map3.put(5, "five");

    Iterator<Entry<Integer, String>> iterator2 = map2.entrySet().iterator();

    while (iterator2.hasNext()) {
        Entry<Integer, String> entry = iterator2.next();
        if (!map1.containsKey(entry.getKey())) {
            map1.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
    }

    System.out.println(map1);

}
```

OUTPUT -

```
{2=two, 4=four, 1=one, 3=three}
```

Try for map3 by yourself.

Comment: To elaborate a bit: Java makes no guarantees about iteration or insertion order for `HashMap`, which is why people are suggesting `LinkedHashMap`. You are not getting the expected order after making the merged map a `LinkedHashMap` b/c the source maps are `HashMap`s (which don't guarantee iteration order). Sanjeev is correctly pointing this out and saying that you need to make the source maps `LinkedHashMap` as well.

Comment: @Sanjeev : selected answer is more dynamic considering the fact that java 8 is used, and in case i have greater maps to be merged instead of just 3